# Create subfolders based on cell value and copy images to same folder

Tags: excel, vba, subdirectory

I am working on a big project and the ability to change the code stopped at this point. So help is needed please.

The main folders have subfolders and MSR files inside which are related to eachother with the naming.We have to input this main folder path into D4 on our excel file. 
The MSR have all the info related to every image. Image folders have all the images inside and we need to sort the all into subfolders.
We already have a macro that retrieves a list on which images are correlated to the correct position. ( see third image)
What we want do now is creating subfolders into the main folder that corresponds to the "*test" in this case and in this new folder there should be subfolders created based on how many unique places there are. In this case it would result in 18 subfolder. The combination of Column D and E are the unique places (first 2 examples = 13200-9496 and 13213-9506). All the image files that corrospond to this place should be put in the new subfolder.

I hope this is somewhat clear?

Main folder overview

[image]

Sub folder overview

[image]

Output data

[image]

Code:

```
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    Dim WBMacro As Workbook
    Set WBMacro = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim FoName As Range
    Set FoName = WBMacro.Sheets("Instructions").Range("B4")


        FolderName = FoName
        If Right(FolderName, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then FolderName = FolderName & Application.PathSeparator
        FName = Dir(FolderName & "*.msr")

        'loop through the files
        Do While Len(FName)

              Dim WBMSR As Workbook
              Set WBMSR = Workbooks.Open(FolderName & FName)

            With WBMSR

    Columns("A:A").Select

        Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
            :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True


     'Create new tab to copy data of interest in
     Dim WsMSR As Worksheet
     Set WsMSR = WBMSR.ActiveSheet
     WsMSR.Name = "MSRData"

     .Worksheets.Add

     Dim wsPictData As Worksheet
     Set wsPictData = WBMSR.Sheets("Sheet1")
     wsPictData.Name = "PictureInfo"

     'Define where to copy data to

     Dim RngPictName As Range
     Dim RngX As Range
     Dim RngY As Range

     Set RngPictName = wsPictData.Range("A2")
     Set RngXY = wsPictData.Range("B2")
     Set RngChipCoX = wsPictData.Range("D2")
     Set RngChipCoY = wsPictData.Range("E2")

     RngPictName.Offset(-1, 0) = "PictName"
     RngXY.Offset(-1, 0) = "DieX,DieY"
     RngChipCoX.Offset(-1, 0) = "ChipCoX"
     RngChipCoY.Offset(-1, 0) = "ChipCoY"


     'Find PictureName

     Dim RngPictStart As Range
     Dim RngPictStop As Range
     Dim RngPict As Range


    Dim strImage As String
    strImage = "&mp_image_name"

    Dim strChipNr As String
    strChipNr = "Chip_number"

    Dim strChipCo As String
    strChipCo = "Chip_coordinate"

    With WsMSR.Range("B:B")

     Set image = .Find(strImage, lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues)

       If Not image Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = image.Address

            Do

                Set pict = image.Offset(0, 2)
                pict.Copy

                    If RngPictName = "" Then
                    RngPictName.PasteSpecial
                    Else
                    RngPictName.Offset(-1, 0).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
                    End If


                For i = 1 To 15

                    'Do

                        If image.Offset(i, 1).Value = strChipNr Then
                        Set XY = image.Offset(i, 2)
                        XY.Copy

                            If RngXY = "" Then
                            RngXY.PasteSpecial
                            Else
                            RngXY.Offset(-1, 0).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
                            End If
                        End If

                        If image.Offset(i, 1).Value = strChipCo Then
                        Set ChipX = image.Offset(i, 2)
                        ChipX.Copy

                            If RngChipCoX = "" Then
                            RngChipCoX.PasteSpecial
                            Else
                            RngChipCoX.Offset(-1, 0).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
                            End If


                        Set ChipY = image.Offset(i, 4)
                        ChipY.Copy

                            If RngChipCoY = "" Then
                            RngChipCoY.PasteSpecial
                            Else
                            RngChipCoY.Offset(-1, 0).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
                            End If
                        End If

                Next


                Set image = .FindNext(image)
                                    If image Is Nothing Then
                                        GoTo DoneFinding1
                                    End If


             Loop While image.Address <> FirstAddress


         End If

    End With

DoneFinding1:

    End With


    ' change wsPictData Column B with (x,Y) to 2 columns (B = X, C = Y)

    With wsPictData

    Columns("B:B").Select

        Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
            :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True



    End With


    WsMSR.Delete
    Dim WBMSRFileName As String
    WBMSRFileName = Left(WBMSR.Name, Len(WBMSR.Name) - 4)
    Dim relativePath As String
    relativePath = WBMSR.Path



    WBMSR.SaveAs Filename:=relativePath & "\" & "Pictures_" & WBMSRFileName & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    WBMSR.Close (False)

      ' go to the next file in the folder

    FName = Dir


    Loop


    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox ("all Files in folder" & relativePath & " are analyzed")
```

This is a schema to clarify the folder tree. Picture test is the main folder (in this example, name is always different). The grey area on the bottom is wat the macro needs to make. Inside Mainfolder, create for every "test" a new folder with appendix "filtered" and in every folder new folders with the location which hold all the images that were taken on that location.

[folder tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7WzO.png)

[msr file example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZrQP.png)

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: What code and were do I need to insert into the existing code to create the new subfolders and copy the related images to the correct folder?

Comment: what part of the code you tried do you have trouble with? creating subfolders? copying a file?

Comment: Well I guess the first thing that has to be done is creating all the matching subfolders but I have no idea were to begin inside this code. Once the subfolders are created, I think I can copy the images to the subfolders but I`m not sure.

Comment: FYI, the code that I showed is an existing and working code. It just has to be upgraded

Comment: so in other words you're looking for someone to write the code for you?

Comment: Can you post an image of a .msr file open in notepad, I assume it is a space delimited text file ?

Comment: Image added on the bottom. It is indeed a space delimited text files with 205 000 lines.
@MarkusDresch if I just get pointed in the wright direction I would prefer to write it myself so I learn but is someone else writes it, it is ok for my but I will still try to understand and mayby manupulate the code to learn

Answer (score 1):

This scans the MAIN_FOLDER for excel files starting with Pictures_, opens them and scans down the rows building the destination folder names from columns A, D and E. I put message boxes at each stage so if you single step through you can study how it works. It will create sub-folders if you confirm the action but the actual copy method at the end is commented out. See [FileSystemObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/filesystemobject-object) for more details.

```vb
Sub imagemove()

    Const MAIN_FOLDER = "c:\temp\msr\"

    Dim FileName As String, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim count As Long, iLastRow As Long, iRow As Long
    Dim sPictureFolder As String, sCopyFolder As String
    Dim sCopySubFolder As String, msg As String
    Dim sPictureName As String, sChipCoX As String, sChipCoY As String
    Dim sSrc As String, sDest As String

    Dim FSO As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    FileName = Dir(MAIN_FOLDER & "Pictures_*.xlsx")
    Do While Len(FileName) > 0

        ' determine picture folder from filename
        sPictureFolder = MAIN_FOLDER & Mid(FileName, 10, Len(FileName) - 14)
        sCopyFolder = sPictureFolder & "-Filtered"
        Debug.Print sPictureFolder, sCopyFolder

        ' check if folder exists
        If FSO.FolderExists(sCopyFolder) = False Then
            msg = sCopyFolder & " does not exist, do you want to create it"
            If vbYes = MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo, "Confirm") Then
                FSO.CreateFolder sCopyFolder
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If

        ' scan down msr file
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MAIN_FOLDER & FileName, False, True)
        Set ws = wb.Sheets("PictureInfo")
        iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
       'Debug.Print FileName, iLastRow

        For iRow = 2 To iLastRow
            sPictureName = ws.Cells(iRow, 1) ' A
            sChipCoX = ws.Cells(iRow, 4) ' D
            sChipCoY = ws.Cells(iRow, 5) ' E

            ' ignore jpeg images
            If Right(sPictureName, 4) = "jpeg" Then GoTo skip

            sCopySubFolder = sCopyFolder & "\" & sChipCoX & "-" & sChipCoY

            ' check if sub folder exists
            If FSO.FolderExists(sCopySubFolder) = False Then
                msg = sCopySubFolder & " does not exist, do you want to create it"
                If vbYes = MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo, "Confirm") Then
                    FSO.CreateFolder sCopySubFolder
                Else
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If

            ' move locations
            sSrc = sPictureFolder & "\" & sPictureName
            sDest = sCopySubFolder & "\" & sPictureName

            ' check file exists
            If FSO.FileExists(sSrc) = True Then
                MsgBox "Copy from " & sSrc & " to " & sDest
               'FSO.CopyFile sSrc, sDest
            Else
                MsgBox sSrc & " does not exist", vbCritical, "File does not exist"
                'test FSO.CreateTextFile sDest
            End If

            Debug.Print "Copy", sSrc, "to", sDest
skip:
        Next

        count = count + 1
        FileName = Dir
    Loop

    MsgBox count & " Pictures_* files scanned in " & MAIN_FOLDER, vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: It is working :) thanks, I realy appreciate that you`ve put in all the message boxes. Because I`m new to the whole coding I always put in msgboxes myself to see if it is working and what value I get back. It took me a while why you did -14 caracters for the file name but if is for the appendix .xlsx...
I also changed the main folder to the value from the original macro. At the end of the first macro I made a call to yours. Is there a difference in speed when I paste the code on the bottom of macro 1 or when I put in 1 line to call for the second macro?

Comment: @Wesley No difference. Are you running the macro from a button ?

Comment: Yes from a button. I m trying to get another code in my comment but is not displayed as a code. Tried with the ` `, <pre>, <code> and ctrl K and it is not working?

Comment: @Wesley Don't code in comments. I can see you want to exclude jpeg files. Let me think about it for a little while. You need to be careful deleting rows inside a loop because you are scanning down to a row that is no longer the last one. Best to scan up using For iRow = iLastrow to 2 step -1. You need to recalc last row after for 2nd loop.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have to answer my question... I deleted all the jpeg files from the Pictures file so these images are not copied so I created another loop. I first had it inside your loop but then it would create an extra extra empty folder. But now I`m afraid that I slowed down the macro by a lot? Is it better to do it inside your loop and then delete the "-" folder in the end?

````
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MAIN_FOLDER & "\" & FileName, False, True)
       Set ws = wb.Sheets("PictureInfo")
       iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
       'Debug.Print FileName, iLastRow

            For iRow = 2 To sLastrow
                If Right(ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Text, 4) = "jpeg" Then ws.Cells(iRow, 1).EntireRow.Delete

            Next

       For iRow = 2 To iLastRow


            sPictureName = ws.Cells(iRow, 1) ' A
            sChipCoX = ws.Cells(iRow, 4) ' D
            sChipCoY = ws.Cells(iRow, 5) ' E
    ```
````

Comment: See my update - no need to delete rows, just skip with goto.